# How to use rest api in client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-stream

Hello today  I have simple code Nodejs express  that work as rest api. It work when i use postman to send request as get method like code below. But i try use it in client. it doesn't work . So can you help find mistake,please?

```
// simple rest api 
router.get('/getuser', function(req, res, next) {
   var connection = getcon();

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    connection.query('SELECT username,password from tbuser', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('Object : ', JSON.stringify(results));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
    connection.end();
});

// client code 
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/users/getuser")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks good, what "doesn't work"? What's happening?

Comment: i try call it client side . it 's not worked.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Tell me, my car is not working. Please give me the fix.

Comment: What if you try to call `http://localhost:3000/getuser` URL instead of your current?

Comment: How you were trying to call from the client side?

Comment: yes but _what exactly_ doesn't work? What errors do you get? (Check your browser's console and/or network tab). If you just keep saying "it doesn't work" it's going to be very difficult to help

Comment: i meant , i don't know what something wrong with?

Comment: @Gangadhar Jannu i try call it using simple angular.

Comment: Did you check the browsers console for any hints?

Comment: oh,i found  `json.parse unexpected end of data at line line collumn 1`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you supply incorrect URL in the client script.
Based on your nodejs code URL must be `http://localhost:3000/getuser`

**UPDATE**

You end your connection before you send results. Just move `connection.end()` inside your callback

```
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('Object : ', JSON.stringify(results));
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: @chenrina did you try to move `connection.end()` inside callback?

Comment: but it dose not have problem.

Comment: i found this error “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”

Comment: This error can happen if you make http request from client to a domain different from you load the script.

Comment: how can i fixed it . while i add this header already in nodejs.    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), a mechanism gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers. Add this before your router:

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Signature');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Key');
      next();
    }
);
```